# Using Appdelegate to create methods for Firebase CRUD in IOS Swift for all viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, appdelegate

I was wondering if this is best practice and if it would cause any issues to my IOS swift app, please note that this is my first time creating a full-fledged IOS app and that I mainly have a web app background.

I've noticed that I'm doing CRUD tasks for different functionalities (chatting, matching users together, displaying user and facebook friends' info) and using Firebase as it's easy for me to store my real-time data and that for each ViewControllers I have somewhat similar functions pulling or updating Firebase data but with different data.

I've also noticed that I can use functions previously declared in the AppDelegate.swift file via the UIApplication class.

My question is this: Can I declare functions beforehand using a factory-like pattern (ie: if grab this data, else if grab other data based on input) in the AppDelegate.swift and then call on those methods in my other ViewControllers?

My main concern is my general unfamiliarity with AppDelegate, I understand how I can implement this and that AppDelegate operates like a notification center but would there be delays or data loss?

Note that this is mainly because I'm trying to refactor and somewhat clean up my code and I notice that simply changing the data structure of my Firebase could negatively impact those functions grabbing and updating data and it would be much easier to change functions from a single location instead of in all ViewControllers.

Comment: You should create a separate system to handle network requests. Definitely don't put in AppDelegate. Check out Alamofire Router set up or Moya framework for some good examples. Might take a little longer to set up but will make your code much cleaner

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#crud--authorization? Also is Moya more preferred? It has an Alamofire layer from what it looks like

Comment: It's really preference on your part I just listed those as some examples to check out. You can also just make a class to hold your networking functions and if you want make it a singleton. There is a lot of stuff out there you can check out regarding this topic but at the very least you should have a separate class to hold your networking code that way it's all in one spot and your not rewriting the same code in multiple view controllers. Moya uses alamofire to make the request and what it does is organize how you set up the requests before they are made. It's a little more advanced though

Comment: There are a few cases where you would handle the network request. For example, if I validate the current user using Firebase queries outside the app delegate to determine if I need to load the login page vs the home page of an app, then there will be a slight delay before the home page is loaded as I have to wait for the login page to load and check. If I include this validation in app delegate the home page loads before ever seeing the login page. But for most others its best to follow the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JustinM (See above comments), I used https://github.com/Moya/Moya to create a FirebaseDB.swift layer that serves as one single layer to query and store User data, etc. into Firebase. Did not have to resort to using AppDelegate.swift